# Programming against a clustered database

Tags: sql, sql-server, cluster-computing

I have a C# application that works against MS SQL Server or Oracle using ADO.NET.

Let's say a customer wants to use some kind of database clustering or synchronous replication for purposes of resilience and/or performance.

Am I correct in assuming that my application code does not have to take any account of this? i.e. that database integrity rules and locking are honoured exactly the same as they are for a standard single database? are there any holes I might fall into?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that my
>   application code does not have to take
>   any account of this?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the only thing you have to worry about is the connection string. Specifically you need to go against the cluster name instead of the node name.

Its a minor point but if you miss it, you can undermine the point of your HA Pair and or Load balancing cluster.